# Jest + Enzyme: test Redux-form

Tags: react-redux, jestjs, jsx, redux-form, enzyme

My application has a lot of redux-form. I am using Jest and Enzyme for unit testing. However, I fail to test the redux-form. My component is a login form like:

```jsx
import { login } from './actions';
export class LoginForm extends React.Component<any, any> {

  onSubmit(values) {
    this.props.login(values, this.props.redirectUrl);
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, status, invalid } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
        <TextField label="Email" name="email">
        <TextField type="password" label="Password" name="password" autoComplete/>
        <Button submit disabled={invalid} loading={status.loading}>
          OK
        </Button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  status: state.login.status,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { login };

const form = reduxForm({ form: 'login' })(LoginForm);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(form);
```

### Mock the store, Import connected component

`redux-form` uses the store to maintain the form inputs. I then use `redux-mock-store`:

```jsx
import ConnectedLoginForm from './LoginForm';

const configureStore = require('redux-mock-store');
const store = mockStore({});
const spy = jest.fn(); 

const wrapper = shallow(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedLoginForm login={spy}/>
  </Provider>);

wrapper.simulate('submit');
expect(spy).toBeCalledWith();
```

But in this way, the `submit` is not simulated, my test case failed:

> Expected mock function to have been called with: []
>   But it was not called.

### Mock the store, Import React component only.

I tried to create redux form from the testing code:

```jsx
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ConnectedLoginForm, { LoginForm } from './LoginForm';

const props = {
  status: new Status(),
  login: spy,
};
const ConnectedForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'login',
  initialValues: {
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: '000000',
  },
})(LoginForm);

const wrapper = shallow(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedForm {...props}/>
  </Provider>);

console.log(wrapper.html());

wrapper.simulate('submit');
expect(spy).toBeCalledWith({
  email: 'test@test.com',
  password: '000000',
});
```

In this case, i still got error of `function not called`. If I add `console.log(wrapper.html())`, I got error:

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or
>   props of "Connect(ConnectedField)". Either wrap the root component in
>   a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to
>   "Connect(ConnectedField)".

I cannot find documentations on official sites of redux-form or redux or jest/enzyme, or even Google.. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I used the real store (as `redux-mock-store` does not support reducers) and redux-form's reducer, it worked for me. Code example:

```
import { createStore, Store, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form: formReducer,
});

let store;

describe('Redux Form', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = createStore(rootReducer);
  });

  it('should submit form with form data', () => {
    const initialValues = {...};
    const onSubmit = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <SomeForm
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
          initialValues={initialValues}
        />
      </Provider>
    );

    const form = wrapper.find(`form`);
    form.simulate('submit');

    const expectedFormValue = {...};
    expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(onSubmit.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual(expectedFormValue);
  });

});
```

Comment: But, I suppose that you are not using redux-form components such as <Field /> or <FieldArray />, I think in that case you should get an error like this "FieldArray must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm("

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here: https://github.com/tylercollier/redux-form-test

In short, you can use shallow dive() function to test higher-order component, but in your case, you have a higher-order component inside a higher-order component.

You need to break you component into two components, the first one is a presentation component, without

```
const form = reduxForm({ form: 'login' })(LoginForm);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(form);
```

You then wrap the first component into the second component (container component).

You can easily test the first component (presentation component)

Answer (score -1):

I had the similar problem. The answer can be found here https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1002.
Long story short, you should pass store as a prop into your form and use .dive() function on the wrapper.

Regards

Pavel

Answer (score -1):

I made a tool which helps with problems like that. It make a test-cases with real data (chrome extension collect it and save to file) which you can run by CLI tool.
I recommend you to try it: https://github.com/wasteCleaner/check-state-management